# Issue in updating parameters template field of a rendering using powershell

Tags: presentation, powershell-extensions

The following is the code which i'm using to update the field values of a rendering.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\ListManagerTask\Adding Contact"
Get-Rendering -Item $item -PlaceHolder "main" | 
    Foreach-Object { 
        Write-Host "$_.ChildRenderings.ToString()"
        $_.DataSource = $null 
        Set-Rendering -Item $item -Instance $_
    }
```

I need to assign value to parameters template. But there is no such property.

Can anyone help me out in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add rendering parameters via Sitecore Powershell, you should make use of the `set-renderingparameter`. It accepts a Hashtable or dictionary of key value pairs.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\ListManagerTask\Adding Contact"

$parameters = @{"SampleKey2"="SampleValue2"}

Get-Rendering -Item $item -PlaceHolder "main" | 
    Foreach-Object { 
        Write-Host "$_.ChildRenderings.ToString()"
        $_.DataSource = $null 
        Set-RenderingParameter -Parameter $parameters | 
        Set-Rendering -Item $item -Instance $_
    }
```

Note that I have not yet tested the script but you can find more information at

[Sitecore Powershell Extension - Set-RenderingParameter](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/presentation/set-renderingparameter)

[Sitecore Powershell Extension - Set-Rendering](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/presentation/set-rendering)

Comment: I believe this requires an installation of 5.1.